# How to get month digit to month name in php

Tags: php

Iam having  date with format "2016-07-20 08:01:49". But I want only date with month as name
like this

```
      July 20, 2016
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can use `date()` method like this:

```
date('M d, Y', strtotime('2016-07-20 08:01:49'));
// Output - July 20, 2016
```

> See more about [date formats in PHP](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.date.php)

Hope this helps!